# Is there a way to change the type of hash for passwords in active direcroty?

Tags: hash, active-directory, ldap

I would like to know what type of hash used for active directory passwords and if there is a way to change the type of hash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user's password hash can be stored in Active Directory using two different proprietory hash algorithms: LM hash and NT hash.

The less secure LM hash is disabled by default by group policy on later Server OS versions but can be reenabled again.

Aside from that the only other way you can affect this is to enable storing passwords with reversible encryption using group policy.

After that is enabled, when you change your password a password filter called RASSFM.DLL is used to store the password using reversible encryption. The key that is used to do this is G$MSRADIUSCHAPKEY, which is stored as a global LSA secret. This key is decrypted using a static key (hardcoded in the DLL). The result of this operation is combined with a 16-byte random value (generated every time someone changes their password) and that key is used to encrypt a Unicode version of the password using the RC4 algorithm.

This information is then saved in the userParameters attribute.